# Why can't I display my ruby on rails app on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to display a very simple app from codecademy and this is the error I'm getting in my browser:

> PagesController#welcome is missing a template for request formats: text/html
>
> NOTE!
> Unless told otherwise, Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name,
> contained in a folder named after its controller. If this controller is an API responding with 204 (No Content),
> which does not require a template, then this error will occur when trying to access it via browser,
> since we expect an HTML template to be rendered for such requests. If that’s the case, carry on.

[My directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Egs.png)

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def welcome
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root ‘pages#welcome’
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

welcome.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Running 'rails server' and getting the above error in my browser. As far as I can tell the files are in the right place and of the right type ... Rails v 6.0.1

Comment: your controller seems to be encosed b/w quotes, remove quotes then refresh the page

Comment: Is `welcome.html.erb` located in a `pages` directory inside your `views` directory?

Comment: Sorry, they're not between quotes in my program. Yes, the welcome.html.erb is in app/views/pages.

Comment: can you run in your terminal: rake routes    and show us response?

Comment: This question falls into the "cannot replicate" category. If taken at face value the code in the this question cannot explain the error, I'm guessing it can be attributed to simple human error like for example a typo in the file name or path. But this is really trivial stuff that can just be generated by running `rails g controller pages welcome` instead of spending a bunch of time troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm guessing the wierd quotes on `root ‘pages#welcome’` are from copy-pasting into the browser?

Comment: after running rake routes: https://imgur.com/a/vdyFo8C

Comment: Try to restart the server `spring stop && rails server`

Comment: Recheck file names, I had weird errors related to `c` letter looks the same in different languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was that my project was in a folder the title of which had a space in it.

After moving the project to a different folder it now works.

This is on rails 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my controller and view that had the issue and the auto-generated the controller and view with

```
rails g controller controllername new create
```